# WinRAR Explorer shows all files in archive root directory from subfolders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, archiving, winrar

Currently, my WinRAR installation shows all files from any archive in the root archive directory and I have no idea how to fix it nor I know what caused it as I did not change any settings I remember.

To make an example, here is archive structure:

```
├───a
│       one.txt
│       two.txt
│       
└───b
        four.txt
        three.txt
```

And here how WinRAR shows it:

```
│   four.txt
│   one.txt
│   three.txt
│   two.txt
│   
├───a
└───b
```

I have checked WinRAR settings, however, I could not manage to find anything relevant. I have also tried to completely remove my installation and install again, however, it did not help.

Windows Explorer and 7Zip work fine.

What would be a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a feature in WinRar you might have triggered it.
Press CTRL + H and it should be back to normal
Also you might try CTRL + T

Comment: Thank you, it was not very intuitive. As a note, it was Flat Folders View (CTRL+H).

Comment: @This solution is a life saver