# A zip file which shows all files in archive root directory from subfolders in a windows file explorer view

Tags: zip, rar

Some one shared me a zip file shown in the windows file explorer that all the files in the subdir are placed in the archive root dir. The hierachy is like the following box:

```
│   fileone.txt......dir/fileone.txt
│   filetwo.txt......dir/filetwo.txt
└───dir
```

And the actuarial hierachy is like the following box:

```
└───dir
        fileone.txt
        filetwo.txt
```

Some one has the similar problem with me, but not the same one: [WinRAR Explorer shows all files in archive root directory from subfolders](https://superuser.com/questions/1185642/winrar-explorer-shows-all-files-in-archive-root-directory-from-subfolders) . How does the person give me the zip file do?

Comment: How does the person giving me the zip file do what? Are you saying that when you VIEW (without extracting) the zip there are no subfolders, just files, and when you EXTRACT the zip there are subfolders? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, does this happen with every zip, or only certain ones? And that linked question looks like exactly the same issue. Could you be more clear how it is different?

Comment: @music2myear When I view the zip in the windows file explorer, it show all files on the archive root and an EMPTY sub folder. But after extracted, it looked like a normal dir with some files. The zip file from a certain person just does the STRANGE thing. If it is created by me, it is just like a normal zip file with a normal tree. I just want to know how the person does.

Comment: @music2myear The difference between mine and the link is we use different viewer to see the inside of a zipped file. I just want the same view under windows file explorer to the view from WinRAR with Ctrl+H toggled.

Comment: @music2myear I know it is weird. I am curious about how the person does.

Comment: Did you ask this person how they did it? Asking the person who does it may be simpler, and have a better chance of getting you an answer, than asking a bunch of Randoms on the internet.